# Accessing nested structures

Tags: c, linked-list, nested, structure

I'm having some trouble accessing the checkups struct that is contained within dog. Since dog is contained within contained I assumed that I would just point to the checkups from dog from the container but that seems to be causing an error when trying to add a checkup date or replace one.

```
    // used to create a linked list of containers, each contaning a "dog"
    struct container {
    struct dog *dog;
    struct container *next;
     } *list = NULL;

    // used to hold dog information and linked list of "checkups"
     struct dog {
        char name[30];
        char breed[30];
        struct checkup *checkups;
    };

  // used to create a linked list of checkups containing "dates"
    struct checkup {
        char date[30];
        struct checkup *next;
    };
```

Here is the code where I try to add a new date to the checkups but when it tried to add it on my program crashes. Any direction on why this would be occurring would be greatly appreciated.

```
    void add_checkup(char* name, char* date)
    {
        struct container *tempList = list;
        struct checkup *tempCheck = (struct checkup *) malloc(sizeof(struct       checkup));
        while (tempList != NULL) {

           if (strcmp(tempList->dog->name, name) == 0) {

                strcpy(tempCheck->date, date);
                strcpy(tempList->dog->checkups, tempCheck);
            }

            tempList->next;
        }


   }
```

Comment: At first glance, I see that you've allocated the memory for the "parent" struct, but you haven't allocated the memory for (each of) the "child" struct(s). As a result of this, `tempList->dog` is just a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `strcpy()` to set the value of a `struct checkup *`?  That attempts to copy the data *pointed to* by the source pointer to the array assumed to be pointed to by destination pointer, when in fact I see no particular reason to suppose that the destination pointer is even valid.  Certainly there's no reason to suppose that the source data has the form of a null-terminated array of `char`, so your original code is badly wrong here.

Simple assignment is more likely to be correct:

```
tempList->dog->checkups = tempCheck;
```

Note, however, that that presents a serious risk of memory leakage because the previous value of tempList->dog->checkups is lost.  Note also that it doesn't match the behavior implied by the *`add_`* part of the function name -- it's more like `set_`.  If you want to be able to maintain more than one checkup per dog then you would need to do more work.

Comment: I originally was trying to copy in the 'char' value of 'date' but instead decided to just make a struct of 'checkups' to be placed in there. I just sort of assumed that using  strcpy() would still work.